# Pure exchange economy: What if a consumer can set prices?

Tags: walrasian

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

Consider an exchange economy with 2 consumers and 2 goods. First, consumer A sets the price, then consumer B maximizes utility according to the price. Then consumer A must make the trade chosen by consumer B.

Now I'm wondering how I should calculate the resulting equilibrium and whether the equilibrium is Pareto optimal. Will consumer A be better off this way, or will consumer A be better off if they both treat prices as given?

Comment: Here is an example of finding equilibrium and checking for its optimality: https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/56308/11824 Argue that consumer A will be at least as well off this way in comparison to the situation when they both treat prices as given.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [General equilibrium with market power](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/56297/general-equilibrium-with-market-power)